# K Zeros between 14641

Tags: probability, combinatorics

One Writes K- Zeros between every two digits of the number 14641. What is the square root of the number obtained?

I want to know if there is a better way of writing out the solution. As of now I know that i would get 1(k-zeros)2(k-zeros)1.

k=1---> 10201
k=2---> 1002001
k=3---> 100020001

I want to define this for all k-zeros.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: powers of $1 + 10^{k+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

The square root of the number where k-zeros are placed between every two digits of 14641 would result in a number of the form

(1+10^(k+1))^2